# Сортировка в php

Tags: php, mysql, сортировка

Всем привет, проблема такая, надо сделать сортировку по принципу 
ссылки на функцию сортировки или как я сделал:

```
if(isset($_GET['sort']) && !empty($_GET['sort']))

{
$order = $_GET['sort'];
 echo $order;
   $removeQuery = "SELECT *  FROM `table_orders` ORDER BY " . $order . "  DESC";

 $Res = mysql_query($removeQuery, $db);

 }
```

а использоваться это будет тут:

```
if($Res) {

 if(mysql_num_rows($Res) > 0) {

        echo "<table  cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' id='table' class='sortable'>";

            echo "<tr>";

                echo "<th><h3><a href='tabledb.php?sort=id'>id</a></h3></th>";

                echo "<th><h3><a href='tabledb.php?sort=servers'>Servers</a></h3></th>";

                echo "<th><h3><a href='tabledb.php?sort=ping'>Ping</a></h3></th>";

                echo "<th><h3><a href='tabledb.php?sort=day'>Day</a></h3></th>";

                echo "<th><h3><a href='tabledb.php?sort=time'>Time</a></h3></th>";

            echo "</tr>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Res)) {
 $id = $row["id"];
       $servers  = $row["servers"];
       $ping   = $row["ping"];
       $day   = $row["day"];
       $time   = $row["time"];
 echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $servers . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $ping . "</td>";
....
```

в общем и т.д.

в общем в первой части кода ошибка, и ошибка не отображается просто не выводит таблицу с данными, что это может быть!? Если надо полный листинг могу скинуть!

Comment: Варнинги, ошибки?

Comment: отрабатывает это

if (!$Res) {
    $message  = 'Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Запрос целиком: ' . $removeQuery;
    die($message); }

Comment: а запрос целиком как выглядит? и что за ошибку выкидывает. Тут ясно дело что проблема в запросе

Comment: первое идет, то что я написал в первой части кода; второе: то что в предыдущем комменте; третье 2-ая часть кода и в итоге просто показывает на белом экране " Неверный запрос: Запрос целиком: " причем не указывает что именно не так!

Comment: если я использую :
$Requete = "SELECT * FROM `table_orders`";
$Result  = mysql_query($Requete, $db);
и  везде подставлю $Result заместо $Res то все гуд отрабатывает!

Comment: Перестаньте использовать mysql_*. Пользуйтесь mysqli_* или PDO http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php. У вас красивая `sql injection` дырка https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.